# Get Relationship of project files and compile dynamically in TFS Build

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a solution with multiple projects.
However, this solution to compile correctly, I need to compile a sequence of projects that are in the solution folder.
As I have many projects, in each folder, need to dynamically obtain the relationship of project files, eg. Csproj, to compile.
I've tried creating tasks, creating xml editing csproj file, but I get no result.

```
    <PropertyGroup>
    <SrcFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..</SrcFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PluginProjectsFiles Include="$(SrcFolder)\Folder\SubFolder.*\*.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="BuildPlugins">
    <Message Text="Building Plugins" />
    <MSBuild Projects="@(PluginProjectsFiles)" Targets="Clean;Build" Properties="Configuration=Release" />
    <Message Text="Plugins Built" />
  </Target>
```